# calling assembly functions from c

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to use a function in assembly, invoked from a C project.  This function is supposed to call a libc function let's say `printf()`, but I keep getting a segmentation fault.

In the .c file I have the declaration of the function let's say

```
int do_shit_in_asm()
```

In the .asm file I have

```
.extern printf
.section .data
         printtext:
              .ascii "test"
.section .text
.global do_shit_in_asm
.type do_shit_in_asm, @function

do_shit_in_asm:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    push printtext
    call printf
    movl %ebp, %esp
    pop %ebp
ret
```

Any <strike>pointers</strike> comments would be appreciated.

```
as func.asm -o func.o

gcc prog.c func.o -o prog
```

Comment: "Any pointers would be appreciated": int *ptr;

Comment: @Sapph +1 but it doesn't help :))

Comment: @Sapph: You meant `void`*, right?

Comment: @Lambert: It's so painfully obvious in retrospect! I'm ashamed. +1 to you sir.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change `push printtext` to `push $printtext`.

As it is, you're loading a value from the address `printtext` and pushing that, rather than pushing the address. Thus, you're passing `'test'` as a 32-bit number, rather than a pointer, and `printf` is trying to interpret that as an address and crashing.

Answer (score 9):

One of the best ways to get started with assembly language functions is to write a similar function in C, and then build it with the compiler switch that generates an assembly listing (`-S` on gcc). Then you can study the output of what the compiler did, and modify as needed.

This is particularly useful if you're calling functions such as `printf` which use a different calling convention (because of the variable number of arguments). Calling those functions may be quite different from calling non-varargs functions.

Comment: Very educational... but also typically very misleading. The real issue is the ABI specific details of what registers must be preserved, what they mean, and how they interact w/the C ABI.  I went down this path initially and then realized that my assembly would be no better than what the compiler would generate which was exactly the opposite of what I was trying to achieve!

Answer (score 6):

the issue was that i was using

```
pushl printtext
```

rather that

```
pushl $printtext
```

Thanks everybody for your help and sorry for wasting your time :P

Comment: You got it just before I posted. Congrats on solving your problem. :-)

Answer (score 2):

After this:

```
push printtext
call printf
```

You want:

```
addl $4, %esp
```

**Further explanation:**

Because you're using x86 Linux I assume the calling convention requires the callee to cleanup the parameters.  Because you pushed a pointer before calling `printf`, your stack is off by 4 after that function's `ret` instruction happened.

**Update:**

Yeah, OK, I was used to Intel syntax so I was getting the order of the arguments backward in my head.  Actually the lack of the `addl` back to `esp` doesn't matter, because you're restoring `esp` correctly near your `ret`.  My next guess is that the string you're passing to `printf` is lacking a null terminator...  Let me see what `gas` does...

**Update 2:**

OK, `gas` null terminates strings for you, so I guess my second hunch was wrong.  It looks like you found the issue so the point is moot.

Comment: I got confused because I'm used to Intel syntax, not AT&T.  You actually want `addl $4, %esp`  Hold on, let me take another look...

Comment: @void - Maybe you can check in a hex editor.  Does the string you pass to printf get null terminated?

Comment: right it's $4, %esp i found the issue, I should have pushed on the stack pushl $prittext